# How can I delete a Google Sheets created by a service account?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I have a python script using [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#creating-a-spreadsheet) to create a Google Sheets using a service user. So the owner of the document is the service user and not me.

How can I easily delete such a document if I am not the onwer but I have the service user details?

[image: google sheet modified by service user]

[image: onwership]

Answer (score 1):

The Client object in the gspread library has a `del_spreadsheet` method. Here's the relevant section of the source code:

```py
class Client:
    def del_spreadsheet(self, file_id):
        """Deletes a spreadsheet.

        :param str file_id: a spreadsheet ID (a.k.a file ID).
        """
        url = "{}/{}".format(DRIVE_FILES_API_V3_URL, file_id)

        params = {"supportsAllDrives": True}
        self.request("delete", url, params=params)
```

So you can use your service account credentials to create a Client with ownership of the spreadsheet using `gspread.service_account`, then call the `del_spreadsheet` method of the Client. `file_id` is the unique ID of the spreadsheet, which you can easily pull from the URL bar when the spreadsheet is open, or using the `id` property of the spreadsheet if you're editing it with gspread.